# Conflict between ViewPager swipe and RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app, I have a `ViewPager` that has different tabs. Each tab is composed only of a `RecyclerView` which can be scrolled vertically.

My problem is that when I try to navigate to other tab and swipe left or right, the `RecyclerView's` scroll is detected first and instead of going to another tab the `RecyclerView` gets scrolled.

I tried following property of recycler view:

```
         rv_home.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

that time `ViewPager` swipe works as expected But vertical scrolling of `recycler view` disabled. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rv_home.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
rv_home.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
rv_home.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Its because you might have taken RecyclerView item as match parent in width. Take that wrap content and it might work for you as well as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 rootView.nested_scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(object : NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener {
        override fun onScrollChange(
            v: NestedScrollView?,
            scrollX: Int,
            scrollY: Int,
            oldScrollX: Int,
            oldScrollY: Int
        ) {

            if (v?.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                    scrollY > oldScrollY
                ) {
                    var visibleItemCount = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).getChildCount()
                    var totalItemCount = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).getItemCount()
                    var pastVisiblesItems =
                        (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                //Load Your Items Here

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.